# Differential equation $y''=e^y $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a quick way of finding $y(t)$ which satisfies the following equation:$$y''=e^y \ ?$$ Usually when given equation $ax''+bx'+cx=0$ I looked for roots of characteristic polynomial, but in this case I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why not Integrate  !!!!

Comment: $$e^y=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)}{dt}$$

$$\implies e^y\ dy=\frac{dy}{dt}\ d\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)$$

$$\implies e^y+k=\frac12\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{2(e^y+K)}$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee your comment would be more appropriate as an answer, preceding with the word **hint**.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate. Commonly occurring trick. because this type of DE shows up in equations of motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice trick to use in general. Multiply each side by $y'$:
$$y'' y' = e^y y'$$
Integrate each side to get
$$\frac{1}{2} (y')^2 = e^y+C.$$
Solve for $y'$:
$$y' = \sqrt{2 e^y + C}.$$
Integrate again:
$$\int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{2 e^y + C}} dx = x + D.$$
Using Wolfram Alpha one gets:
$$-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \tanh^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{C+2e^y}{C}} \right) = x + D.$$
I will leave it to you to solve for $y$.

Comment: +1 for the multiplication trick, but you should explain the integral, WA is not an answer (it could be wrong, WA too has bugs)

Comment: totally, this integral doesn't look amicable, how can one calculate it without using Wolfram?

Comment: @Jules

$$\int \frac{y'}{\sqrt{2 e^y + C}} dx = x + D.$$

change of variables $v^2 = 2e^y + C$ leads to
$$
\int \frac{1}{v}\frac{2v}{\left(v^2-C\right)}dv = -\frac{2}{C}\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{C}}dv
$$
change to $u^2 = v^2/C$ to clean up the integral we have
$$
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{C}}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}du = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{C}}\int \frac{d}{du}\tanh^{-1}(u)du = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{C}}\tanh^{-1}(u) = x + D_{1}
$$ then transforming back to $y$ by $u=\sqrt{\frac{2e^y+C}{C}}$.

Comment: You can always differentiate the answer given by Wolfram to see if this answer is ok.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the "ad hocness" of multiplying by $y'$ and then integrating, you can take note that since the ODE has translational symmetry in $x$, if we write out the ODE in terms of $x=x(y)$ it will be first order in $x'$: $\displaystyle x'=\frac{1}{y'}$, $\displaystyle x''=-x'^3e^y\implies -\frac{x''}{x'^3}=e^y$, and now integrating with respect to $y$ gives $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x'^2}-e^y= $ const $\displaystyle \implies \frac{y'^2}{2}-e^y= $ const. and this can be written as a separable ODE and so can be reduced to quadrature.

Comment: What is "translational symmetry"?

Comment: @Taladris If $y_1=y_1(x)$ is a solution of the problem, then so is $y_2(x)=y_1(x+t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.